# How to push in Mongoose sub sub document array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Following is my schema:**

```
new Schema({
    user: [{
        email: { type: String },
        contactList: [{
            frndemail: { type: String },
            msgList: [{
                from : String,
                to : String,
                content : String,
                time : String, 
                type: String,
                subtype : String,
                state: String
            }],
            unreadmsgList:[{
                from : String,
                to : String,
                content : String,
                time : String, 
                type: String,
                subtype : String,
                state: String
            }]      
        }]
    }]
});
```

In the above schema i am trying to push new messages in the msgList, but my query is not working i am trying something like this:

```
MyModel.update({"user.email":"myemail@gmail.com","user.contactList.frndemail":"frndemail@gmail.com"}, {
                $push:{"user.$.contactList.$.msgList":{
                    "from": "myemail@gmail.com",
                    "to": "frndemail@gmail.com",
                    "content": "abc",
                    "time": "1:00 PM",
                    "type": "",
                    "subtype": "",
                    "state": ""
                }}
            },
        function(err,doc){
            if (err) {
                console.log("msg creation failed " +err);
            } else {
                console.log("msg created successfully "+doc);
            }
        });
```

Please if anyone correct this query for me thanks...

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: this is the error : user msg creation failed CastError: Cast to [string] failed for value "[{"from":"myemail@gmail.com","to":"frndemail@gmail.com","content":"avc","time":"5:32 PM","type":"text","subtype":"text","state":"NONE"}]" at path "msgList"

Comment: one thing is mongo will not allow $ positional operator more than once in a field.{"user.$.contactList.$.msgList"}

Comment: I don't if it is required but your schema needs to be optizimed. You should keep users and massages in diferent Schemea. Also no need to make to diffrent arrays for read and unread messages.